# Installing packages requires CDROM

Tags: apt

On my machine that I just setup, I'm trying to install OpenSSH but it requires me to have a CDROM with me every time I try to install a package. I know this seems like an easy fix to you all, change `/etc/apt/sources.list` or whatever and comment out a line. The problem is: I don't have `nano` installed on my machine

For whatever reason it doesn't come preinstalled on the installation disk and I can't install it because I can't install any packages.

Is there like a default editor that I don't know about, or will I have to do some `echo "blah" < file.txt` stuff?

This is really confusing me and I just want to run some servers off of my linux machine.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running Ubuntu off of a disk, it will automatically have the CD-ROM repository active.

If you are using Ubuntu Desktop, you just need to go to "Software & Updates" and under the "Installable from CD-ROM/DVD" section, uncheck the box next to the CD/DVD name.

If you are using Ubuntu Server, you can remove all repositories with "CD-ROM" in their name using "sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list" and by saving the file and running "sudo apt update".

In the case of a Broken/Corrupt sources.list, you can use this website to generate a new sources.list to replace the old one: https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Also, please post your version of Ubuntu, that would make it easier, ty!

Answer (score 2):

vi is a good editor and is installed by default by the OS.

Comment: Didn't know about vi, I was able to edit the file, but now I'm running into another problem: There are no other lines in the file showing where the download are at, and it cannot find the repos to download.